# Undefined variable: alert Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Hey guys I am new to laravel and I have been trying to store all records of table 'alert' to a variable and then pass that variable to a view so that I can display them.

I have a controller - AlertController and inside that a function:

```
public function showalert(){
        $alert = Alert::all()->toArray();
        return view('content')->with(compact('alert'));

    }
```

In my view I have this code

```
@foreach($alert as $title)
            {{$title->text}}
        @endforeach
```

I am receiving this error :Undefined variable: alert (View: \views\content.blade.php)

Comment: You are returning a redirect, not a view, to return a view use this syntax `return view('view-name')->with(compact('alert'));`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
// controller file

public function showalert(){
        $alert = Alert::all();
        return view('content', [ 'alert' => $alert ]);

    }

// view file

    @foreach($alert as $title)
                {{$title->text}}
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach:

```
public function showalert(){
        $alert = Alert::all();
        return view('content', compact('alert'));

    }
```